# compile error with char * as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(const T & t) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base<char *> {
    void foo(const char  * & t) override {};
};
```

I get compile error

> void Derived::foo(const char*&)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override.

Why isn't `char *` a valid template argument?

Comment: Typo: you need to write `char * const& t`. `const (char*)` is `char *const`, not `const char*`

Comment: `const char*` = `char const*` you want `char* const`. Edit  I'm typing too slow...

Comment: @Justin No, I don't think a confusion over east-const and west-const styles, and the resulting errors, count as a typo.

Comment: @cigien Fair enough

Comment: There must be a dupe out there for this question... anyhow, now just easy pickings for the 50k+ guys.

Comment: East const, west const, how did we manage to escape stuff like,  "<expletive deleted>! Those east const <expletive deleted>ers capped Linus Torvalds. Get the crew together. Gonna <expletive deleted>ing make them <expletive deleted>ing PAY!"

Comment: `void foo(std::add_const<char*>::type& t) override {}` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have

```
virtual void foo(const T & t) = 0;
```

and `T` is a `char *`, then the function type is not `const char *`. The `const` applies to `T`, so what you really have is a `char * const`.  That means your overriding function would need to be

```
void foo(char* const& t) override {};
```

Comment: Seems like an ideal place to plug the east-const style :)

Comment: @cigien Sorry, I live in the mid-west ;)

Answer (score 4):

### West const worst const east const best const

Const applies to the part of the type to its left.  If and only if there is nothing to its left (or a bracket or other scope limiter) does it apply to the thing on its right.

East const refers to putting const, by habit, to the right (east) of the thing you want const.

West const is the habit of putting const to the left.

The problem with west const is that

```
const char*
```

is actually

```
char const*
```

not

```
char* const
```

which is the source of your bug.

In west const style, `const T` when `T` is `char*` is `char*const`.  Surprising.

In east const style, `T const` when `T` is `char*` is `char*const`.  Not surprising at all.

So `T const&` when `T` is `char*` is `char*const&`, not `const char*&` (aka `char const*&`) as you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer. This is much more useful than simply pointing out that the syntax is wrong, and showing a fix. This answer suggests a way to avoid a myriad variety of bugs that arise from `const` being placed to the West.

Answer (score 1):

For immediate solution to compilation error:

```
struct Derived : Base<char *> {
    void foo(char* const& t) override {};
};
```

`const char*` denotes pointer to constant character, but you need a reference to constant character pointer. This is not the same as the former, and requires different placement of `const`-qualifier.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained _why_

Comment: @MooingDuck just typing and editing on the fly.